# Mac Segmentation fault on Unix Executable File, file compilation is fine

Tags: c++, c, macos

I am trying to run a code scheme published in the following paper:
http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1001059#s4

Specifically, the implementation of the code is from:
http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~rpsysbio/pada/

Following successful compilation of the below code on Mac OS X El Capitan using gcc Fortran, I get an executable file as expected from the code below.  However, when I try to execute this file I get

> segmentation fault 11.

After some research I think this is a recursion problem causing the stack to overflow, but I have no idea how to solve this.  Could someone point me in the right direction please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "./3rdparty/dSFMT-src-2.0/dSFMT.c"

double          x1,
                x1p,
                x1preN;
double          x2,
                x2p,
                x2preN;
double          x3,
                x3p,
                x3preN;
double          x4,
                x4p,
                x4preN;
double          k1;
double          k2;
double          k3;
int             x1ctr[100][5][5][5][5][5][5][5];
int             x2ctr[100][5][5][5][5][5][5][5];
int             x3ctr[100][5][5][5][5][5][5];
int             x4ctr[100][5][5][5][5];

double
fx1(double x1)
{
    return -(k1 * x1 * x3 - k2 * x2) + k3 * x2;
}
double
fx2(double x2)
{
    return (k1 * x1 * x3 - k2 * x2) - k3 * x2;
}
double
fx3(double x3)
{
    return -(k1 * x1 * x3 - k2 * x2);
}
double
fx4(double x4)
{
    return k3 * x2;
}


int
discretize(double v, double xi[], int length)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < length - 1; j++)
    if (v < xi[j])
        return j - 1;
    return length - 2;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int             myid = atoi(argv[1]);
    double          dt = 0.01,
    halfdt = dt / 2.0;
    int             tps = (int) (10.0 / dt),
    t,
    i;
    int             block = tps / 100,
    tb;
    double          halfF1,
                    halfF2,
                    F3,
                    F4;
    double          x1i[] = { 0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0 };
    double          x2i[] = { 0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0 };
    double          x3i[] = { 0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0 };
    double          x4i[] = { 0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0 };

    int             x1pre,
                    x1post,
                    x1init = 2;
    int             x2pre,
                    x2post,
                    x2init = 0;
    int             x3pre,
                    x3post,
                    x3init = 4;
    int             x4pre,
                    x4post,
                    x4init = 0;
    double          k1i[] =
    { 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0 };
    double          k2i[] =
    { 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0 };
    double          k3i[] =
    { 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0 };
    int             k1bin;
    int             k2bin;
    int             k3bin;



    int             sampleNo = 1000;
    dsfmt_t         dsfmt;
    int             seed = 7018 + myid;
    dsfmt_init_gen_rand(&dsfmt, seed);


    for (int i = 0; i < sampleNo; i++) {
    k1 = 0.0 + dsfmt_genrand_close_open(&dsfmt) * 1.0;
    k2 = 0.0 + dsfmt_genrand_close_open(&dsfmt) * 1.0;
    k3 = 0.0 + dsfmt_genrand_close_open(&dsfmt) * 1.0;
    x1 = x1i[x1init] +
        dsfmt_genrand_close_open(&dsfmt) * (x1i[x1init + 1] -
                    x1i[x1init]);
    x2 = x2i[x2init] +
        dsfmt_genrand_close_open(&dsfmt) * (x2i[x2init + 1] -
                        x2i[x2init]);
    x3 = x3i[x3init] +
        dsfmt_genrand_close_open(&dsfmt) * (x3i[x3init + 1] -
                        x3i[x3init]);
    x4 = x4i[x4init] +
        dsfmt_genrand_close_open(&dsfmt) * (x4i[x4init + 1] -
                        x4i[x4init]);
    x1preN = x1;
    x2preN = x2;
    x3preN = x3;
    x4preN = x4;
    k1bin = discretize(k1, k1i, 6);
    k2bin = discretize(k2, k2i, 6);
    k3bin = discretize(k3, k3i, 6);

    for (int t = 1; t <= tps; t++) {
        // x1
        halfF1 = halfdt * fx1(x1);
        halfF2 = halfdt * fx1(x1 + halfF1);
        F3 = dt * fx1(x1 + halfF2);
        F4 = dt * fx1(x1 + F3);
        x1p = x1 + (2 * halfF1 + 4 * halfF2 + 2 * F3 + F4) / 6.0;
        // x2
        halfF1 = halfdt * fx2(x2);
        halfF2 = halfdt * fx2(x2 + halfF1);
        F3 = dt * fx2(x2 + halfF2);
        F4 = dt * fx2(x2 + F3);
        x2p = x2 + (2 * halfF1 + 4 * halfF2 + 2 * F3 + F4) / 6.0;
        // x3
        halfF1 = halfdt * fx3(x3);
        halfF2 = halfdt * fx3(x3 + halfF1);
        F3 = dt * fx3(x3 + halfF2);
        F4 = dt * fx3(x3 + F3);
        x3p = x3 + (2 * halfF1 + 4 * halfF2 + 2 * F3 + F4) / 6.0;
        // x4
        halfF1 = halfdt * fx4(x4);
        halfF2 = halfdt * fx4(x4 + halfF1);
        F3 = dt * fx4(x4 + halfF2);
        F4 = dt * fx4(x4 + F3);
        x4p = x4 + (2 * halfF1 + 4 * halfF2 + 2 * F3 + F4) / 6.0;
        if (t % block == 0) {
        tb = t / block - 1;
        x1pre = discretize(x1preN, x1i, 6);
        x2pre = discretize(x2preN, x2i, 6);
        x3pre = discretize(x3preN, x3i, 6);
        x4pre = discretize(x4preN, x4i, 6);

        x1post = discretize(x1, x1i, 6);
        x2post = discretize(x2, x2i, 6);
        x3post = discretize(x3, x3i, 6);
        x4post = discretize(x4, x4i, 6);


        x1ctr[tb][k1bin][k2bin][k3bin][x1pre][x2pre][x3pre]
            [x1post]++;
        x2ctr[tb][k1bin][k2bin][k3bin][x1pre][x2pre][x3pre]
            [x2post]++;
        x3ctr[tb][k1bin][k2bin][x1pre][x2pre][x3pre][x3post]++;
        x4ctr[tb][k3bin][x2pre][x4pre][x4post]++;
        x1preN = x1;
        x2preN = x2;
        x3preN = x3;
        x4preN = x4;
        }
        x1 = x1p;
        x2 = x2p;
        x3 = x3p;
        x4 = x4p;
    }
    }


    // output
    FILE           *out;
    char            buffer[256];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "dummy.txt");
    int             idx = 0;

    for (tb = 0; tb < 100; tb++) {
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
         "./models/toy/batct/toyCTx1T%d_%d.txt", tb, myid);
    out = fopen(buffer, "w");
    idx = 0;


    for (int ki0 = 0; ki0 < 5; ki0++)
        for (int ki1 = 0; ki1 < 5; ki1++)
        for (int ki2 = 0; ki2 < 5; ki2++)
            for (int vi0 = 0; vi0 < 5; vi0++)
            for (int vi1 = 0; vi1 < 5; vi1++)
                for (int vi2 = 0; vi2 < 5; vi2++)
                for (int vi = 0; vi < 5; vi++) {
                    int             ctrtmp =
                    (x1ctr[tb][ki0][ki1][ki2][vi0][vi1]
                     [vi2][vi]);
                    if (ctrtmp > 0) {
                    fprintf(out, "%d %d\n", idx,
                        ctrtmp);
                    }
                    idx++;
                }
    fclose(out);
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
         "./models/toy/batct/toyCTx2T%d_%d.txt", tb, myid);
    out = fopen(buffer, "w");
    idx = 0;


    for (int ki0 = 0; ki0 < 5; ki0++)
        for (int ki1 = 0; ki1 < 5; ki1++)
        for (int ki2 = 0; ki2 < 5; ki2++)
            for (int vi0 = 0; vi0 < 5; vi0++)
            for (int vi1 = 0; vi1 < 5; vi1++)
                for (int vi2 = 0; vi2 < 5; vi2++)
                for (int vi = 0; vi < 5; vi++) {
                    int             ctrtmp =
                    (x2ctr[tb][ki0][ki1][ki2][vi0][vi1]
                     [vi2][vi]);
                    if (ctrtmp > 0) {
                    fprintf(out, "%d %d\n", idx,
                        ctrtmp);
                    }
                    idx++;
                }
    fclose(out);
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
         "./models/toy/batct/toyCTx3T%d_%d.txt", tb, myid);
    out = fopen(buffer, "w");
    idx = 0;


    for (int ki0 = 0; ki0 < 5; ki0++)
        for (int ki1 = 0; ki1 < 5; ki1++)
        for (int vi0 = 0; vi0 < 5; vi0++)
            for (int vi1 = 0; vi1 < 5; vi1++)
            for (int vi2 = 0; vi2 < 5; vi2++)
                for (int vi = 0; vi < 5; vi++) {
                int             ctrtmp =
                    (x3ctr[tb][ki0][ki1][vi0][vi1][vi2]
                     [vi]);
                if (ctrtmp > 0) {
                    fprintf(out, "%d %d\n", idx, ctrtmp);
                }
                idx++;
                }
    fclose(out);
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
         "./models/toy/batct/toyCTx4T%d_%d.txt", tb, myid);
    out = fopen(buffer, "w");
    idx = 0;


    for (int ki0 = 0; ki0 < 5; ki0++)
        for (int vi0 = 0; vi0 < 5; vi0++)
        for (int vi1 = 0; vi1 < 5; vi1++)
            for (int vi = 0; vi < 5; vi++) {
            int             ctrtmp =
                (x4ctr[tb][ki0][vi0][vi1][vi]);
            if (ctrtmp > 0) {
                fprintf(out, "%d %d\n", idx, ctrtmp);
            }
            idx++;
            }
    fclose(out);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard something about code indentation?

Comment: Remove parts of the code until the error disappears, then add parts back until you know what line causes the problem. Actually this is also the process you should do before posting a wall of code here. A [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps others to help you and in the best case you can fix the error yourself in the process of creating one

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone can help unless you provide this "custom file": `#include "../3rdparty/dSFMT-src-2.0/dSFMT.c"`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there are others, but I see only two things that can generate a crash.

1. you get the `myid` integer from this instruction

   `int             myid = atoi(argv[1]);`

But if you call the program without passing the id parameter? `argv[1]` is `NULL`. Crash!

Suggestion: define a default id and check `argc`; something like

```
int             myid = (argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : defId);
```

2. you `fopen()` the output files but you don't check the success of the opening; so, when you write in the files, like in

   `fprintf(out, "%d %d\n", idx,
           ctrtmp);`

   in case of failure, in opening the file, `out` is `NULL`. Crash!

Suggestion: check the opening of the output files (`out != NULL`).

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.